# SQL ERROR when i try to do a delete from using 2 tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-error-1064

I'm using MariaDB.
Im trying to do a delete using this two tables:

Table LINPED:

```
CREATE TABLE LINPED (
    NUMPEDIDO SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    NUMLINEA SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    NUMPIEZA CHAR(16),
    PRECIOCOMPRA INTEGER,
    CANTPEDIDA SMALLINT,
    FECHARECEP datetime,
    CANTRECIBIDA SMALLINT);
```

Table PEDIDO:

```
CREATE TABLE PEDIDO (
    NUMPEDIDO SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    NUMVEND SMALLINT,
    FECHA datetime);
```

At first i try to do that:

```
DELETE FROM LINPED
INNER JOIN PEDIDO 
ON LINPED.NUMPEDIDO = PEDIDO.NUMPEDIDO
WHERE PEDIDO.NUMVEND= 1 AND PEDIDO.NUMPEDIDO= 1
```

### **But it not works for me because i get this error:**

[Window Title]
sesion1: Error

[Content]
Error de SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN PEDIDO 
    ON LINPED.NUMPEDIDO = PEDIDO.NUMPEDIDO
    WHERE numven' at line 2

[Aceptar]

[Footer]
Encontrar ayuda acerca de este error

---

**Searching for a solution in Stackoverfolw I found one similar question with this solution:**

```
DELETE FROM LINPED
JOIN PEDIDO ON LINPED.NUMPEDIDO = PEDIDO.NUMPEDIDO
WHERE PEDIDO.NUMVEND = 1 AND PEDIDO.NUMPEDIDO = 1
```

But it not works, at least for me

[Window Title]
sesion1: Error

[Content]
Error de SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN PEDIDO ON LINPED.NUMPEDIDO = PEDIDO.NUMPEDIDO
WHERE PEDIDO.NUMVEND = 1 AND' at line 2

[Aceptar]

[Footer]
Encontrar ayuda acerca de este error

Comment: Instead of `DELETE FROM LINPED ...`, try `DELETE LINPED FROM LINPED ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete from `LINPED` table explicitly using the following:

```
DELETE l.*
FROM LINPED AS l
INNER JOIN PEDIDO AS p
ON l.NUMPEDIDO = p.NUMPEDIDO
WHERE p.NUMVEND = 1 AND p.NUMPEDIDO = 1
```